# problem with javascript and css in html page using windows xp chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, windows-xp

**problem in using code HTML, CSS, JS in chrome xp**

hi i got this function that do brightnes on full page by clicking on button

```html
<html id="html">
    <button onclick="brightness()">lightting</button>
    <script>
    function brightness(){document.getElementById('html').style.filter = 
    "brightness(140%)";}
</script>
</html>
```

the code work in other chrome browsers (like chrome version 90) but in windows xp chrome its not what the problem (is it the javascript?)? what can i change so it will work?

Comment: Wait - are you using running Chrome on Windows XP? In 2022? What Chrome version is that?

Answer (score 2):

[MDN brightness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness) says full support since v18

but

Chrome 49 is the last version to run on XP and according to [can I use brightness](https://caniuse.com/?search=brightness) you need -webkit

[image]

```js
function brightness() {
  document.getElementById('html').classList.toggle("bright");
}
```

```css
.bright {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(140%);
  filter: brightness(140%);
}
```

```html
<html id="html">
<button onclick="brightness()">lighting</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Chrome you are running on your Windows XP, but according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_filter-function_brightness), CSS-filters such as brightness were added in Chrome version 18, and have been supported since 2010.

If you're running an older version of chrome, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to click on the 18-52 link at caniuse - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71999115/295783)